Unable to find the Wildcard directive in my CSP
I conducted a ZAP assessment on my application, I received a flag 'CSP: Wildcard Directive' which has high confidence level. Still, I have not been able to locate the source of the wildcard directive. The CSP I use now:
script-src 'self' 'nonce-randomNonce' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://lh3.ggpht.com/; style-src 'self' 'nonce-randomNonce' https://fonts.googleapis.com/; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/; img-src 'self' https://maps.gstatic.com/ ; worker-src 'self' blob:; connect-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/;

Some notes:

The nonce in the header has been hardcoded as I am still working on generating random nonces

I expect the test to pass without any warnings since I am not using '*' anywhere.


Can someone find what is responsible for Wildcard Directive flag, or what is it that I am missing?
Thanks!

Have you looked at the full details of the ZAP alert? ZAP should give you lots more info.

There are a set of CSP directives that do not fall back to default source. If you haven't defined them it's the same as setting *

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/8700

If you check the "Other Info" of the alert you should see specifics.

https://web.dev/articles/csp#resource-options


The following directives don't use default-src as a fallback. Remember that failing to set them is the same as allowing anything:

base-uri
form-action
frame-ancestors
plugin-types
report-uri
sandbox



Allow me to nitpick on some details here: Setting a directive source to * is not the same as not defining a directive. * is a host-source wildcard, which means it will allow any source for the current and upgraded (secure) scheme. * will not allow wss:, data:, blob: etc. The directive plugin-types is no longer part of the specification. You are not "allowing anything" by not setting report-uri.

That's fair, it's a generalized statement. When we separate it into another alert, I'll see if some additional changes are practical.
